# Problems installing bspwm

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install BSPwm via following the guide here: https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies

I have installed all the dependencies, and followed all the instructions exactly. However when I try "make" in the terminal I get:

```
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/include -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L        -DVERSION=\"0.8.7\" -Os  -c -o bspwm.o bspwm.c
bspwm.c:37:26: fatal error: xcb/xinerama.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [bspwm.o] Error 1
```

There's not a lot of documentation around for bspwm and I can't find any ideas on Google as how to fix this problem. If anyone has any idea what could possibly be the problem please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install libxinerama packages, via

```
sudo apt-get install libxinerama1 libxinerama-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

To find to which package your include file (`X11/extensions/Xinerama.h`) belong to, install `apt-file` and search for it, example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search "X11/extensions/Xinerama.h"
libxinerama-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/Xinerama.h
```

Once you've the package name, install via:

```
sudo apt-get install libxinerama-dev
```

This method is especially useful when there are more similar dependencies like that, so you don't have to guess.

Comment: This is useful, but you have to mention that `apt-file update` downloads (fetches) more than 100MB. In my particular case, it downloaded 204MB.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the original libxinerama packages for this, you need the xcb based ones.

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinerama0-dev
```

Keep that as a note when you see you're missing other headers, you might just need the xcb versions.